# Mybatis creates an association ignoring the notNullColumn setting

Tags: mybatis

I have defined a resultMap in MyBatis with the following association tag:

```
    <association property="copromotor3" javaType="amc.mb.mrcornelis.domain.Onderzoeker" notNullColumn="Copromotor3_CPRID" not>
        <id property="persoonId" column="Copromotor3_CPRID" typeHandler="amc.mb.mrcornelis.persistence.DoctorCpridTypeHandler"/>
        <result property="amcgebruikersnaam" column="Copromotor3_UID"/>
        <result property="achternaam" column="Copromotor3_achternaam"/> 
    </association>
```

The field Copromotor3_CPRID is of type varchar (hence the DoctorCpridTypeHandler which converts the string into an int). Unfortunately if the Copromotor3_CPRID field has no value an instance of amc.mb.mrcornelis.domain.Onderzoeker is created and added as an association. I get the feeling that the value is not null but empty. In both cases i do not want an association. Who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Just do not select the associated records you don't need.

Modify the query and add a predicate to the associated table join that filters out records with `null` and empty value: `Copromotor3_CPRID IS NOT NULL AND Copromotor3_CPRID != ''`.